# Determine two unknown vectors to satisfy parallel and perpendicular conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the vectors $\vec{a} = (1, 2, 1)$ and $\vec{b} = (1, 2, -2)$, determine vectors $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ such that $\vec{a} = \vec{p} + \vec{q}$ and $\vec{p}$ being parallel with $\vec{b}$, while $\vec{q}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{b}$.

I know that in order for two vectors to be perpendicular, the dot product has to be 0 ($\vec{p} \cdot \vec{q} = 0$). If we assume that $\vec{q} = (x, y, z)$, we get the equation $x + 2y - 2z = 0$ or $x = 2z - 2y$. By substituting $x = 0$, we know that one vector perpendicular to $\vec{b}$ must have the coordinates $(0, 1, 1)$.

I also know that $\vec{p}$ can be expressed as $\vec{p} = k\vec{b}$, where $k$ is a constant.

However, I am struggling to figure out how how to proceed from here and satisfy all of the conditions. I suspect a system of equations has to be used due to the amount of unknown variables.

Comment: Do you know how to find the orthogonal projection of $a$ onto $b$? Once you have that you're almost done. Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, I do know the formula for the orthogonal projection but I am a bit confused how it is equivalent to being parallel to vector b.

Comment: The projection onto the subspace spanned by $b$ will be in the direction of $b$ because it will be in the form $kb$ with $k$ some scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to start with noticing that since $\vec{p}$ is parallel to $\vec{b}$,
$$\vec{p}=k\vec{b}=k(1,2,-2)=(k,2k,-2k)$$

Another given condition is:

$$\vec{a}=\vec{p}+\vec{q} \implies \vec{q}=\vec{a}-\vec{p}$$

Plugging in our $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{a}$ gives:

$$\vec{q}=(1,2,1)-(k,2k,-2k)=(1-k,2-2k,1+2k)$$

Finally, we can use the fact that $\vec{b}\cdot\vec{q}=0$ to find $k$:

$$(1,2,-2)\cdot(1-k,2-2k,1+2k)=0 \implies 1-k+2(2-2k)-2(1+2k)=0 $$

$$\implies 1-k+4-4k-2-4k=0 \implies 9k=3 \implies k=\frac{1}{3}$$

To conclude,

$$\fbox{$\vec{p}=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3}) , \space \text{and} \space \vec{q}=(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3}, \frac{5}{3})$}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and solution, this is precisely what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The orthogonal projection of $\vec{a}$ onto $\vec{b}$ will give you the vector $\vec{p}$ 
$\left( \text{Recall that}  \hspace{10pt} \text{proj}_\vec{b}\vec{a}=\dfrac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|^2}\vec{b} \right)$.

Take $\vec{q}=\vec{a}-\vec{p}$. 
You can verify algebraically that this works but you should also convenience yourself that this is geometrically intuitive.